# Log files not rolling

Tags: log4net

So this is the code:

```
 <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender_message" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
  <file value="Tickers\Ticker1.txt" />
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
    <stringToMatch value="|Parser|DynamicData|1|" />
  </filter>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Once" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="3" />
  <maximumFileSize value="5KB" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

I don't understand why the log files keep growing without rolling to another file. not even for days, not to mention the 5KB limit I stated in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<rollingStyle value="Once" />
```

You've got your [`RollingStyle`](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.html) config set to `Once` - "Roll files once per program execution" - so if this is a long-runnig service, it will not roll the file. You should instead use `Size` - "Roll files based only on the size of the file"